# No android in eclipse under Windows > Preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have updated my eclipse to find that I can no long build my android applications. I have been to Help > install new software and tried to the developers SDK and it says it's already install (which I have comfirmed by checking "what is already installed". When I then go to Windows > Preferences there is no android. I have found from searching people recommend unistalling and reinstalling the plug-ins (by going Help > about eclipse SDK > Installation details), However it will not allow me to unistall any of them, including Android Developent Tools. Can Anyone help?

Comment: recommend you to start your eclipse as admin and see what is happening?

Comment: already tried going to delete the entries in the Windows registry for a successful uninstall?

Comment: @VendettaDroid Ok, yer thats given me ability to unistall plug-ins (I had to do every android one) and the re install has allowed android in preferences. Thanks

Comment: I am putting that up as answer. Mark it correct.

Comment: @VendettaDroid Yep, all good now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to start your eclipse as admin. It will allow you to atleast uninstall plugin.

Comment: Ok, yer thats given me ability to unistall plug-ins (I had to do every android one) and the re install has allowed android in preferences and all else went as wanted. Thanks!